# _double.Equals(_float);

Tags: c#, floating-point

Sample code:

```
double d = 0;
float  f = 0;

// Dump() prints result in LinqPad application

(f == d).Dump(); // 1) true
(d == f).Dump(); // 2) true

(f.Equals(d)).Dump(); // 3) false
(d.Equals(f)).Dump(); // 4) true
```

1) returns true as expected
2) same as above
3) false - because we using `Equals(object)`, and it checks internally:

```
  public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj is Single)) {
            return false;
        }
        ...
```

4) true? why?

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj is Double)) {
            return false;
        }
```

How `float` can pass this `if` guard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function called is [public bool Equals(Double obj)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,189) (instead of `public override bool Equals(Object obj)`) which is:

```
public bool Equals(Double obj)
{
    if (obj == m_value) {
        return true;
    }
    return IsNaN(obj) && IsNaN(m_value);
}
```

Thanks to the implicit cast of `float` to `Double`

Comment: 0_0 Another stupid question asked by me :( I moved cursor over Equals, and I swear I saw Equals(object obj) in tool tip in Visual Studio. Guess Im too long in work today :)

Comment: @zgnilec sometimes VS isn't as intelligent as we'd like it to be and you probably seen this.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't.

The overload you're using in case 4 is `double.Equals(double obj)`. This is because there is an implicit conversion from `float` to `double`.

In case 3, there is no implicit conversion from `double` to `float`, as it may result in a loss of precision.  In this case, `double` will be boxed and you're using `object.Equals`.

You can show the actual result of `object.Equals` by casting to object:

```
d.Equals((object)f)).Dump(); // this will be false
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VUGmVt).

Comment: You can use `(d.Equals((object)f)).Dump();` to call the object.`Equals(object)` method and verify the answer.

Comment: @DStanley yep, that's in the fiddle. I'll add the code to the answer as that's probably more helpful. Thanks!